# see all console log Nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, python-3.x, localhost, gunicorn

I run a app in django in local host and for testing my code I can see result by

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and see every detail in that terminal, for example in `views.py` I write a basic code `print("****")` and see the result that my codes works or not, now I moved to production from local host and I used `Ngnix` and `Gunicorn`, I want to test same thing for testing my codes, but I don't find where I should check to find the result of `print("****")` in `views.py`

Answer (score 2):

In Unix systems in Django production, you can check stdout in gunicorn log files like this:

```
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
```

To go to the last lines in log files you need to press **shift** + **G**

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't concurrently the result, i found this is better way to see what is happening
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog